# Need sum of column while selecting other value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
   empID      name       amt      Date
   ------------------------------------
     1        mark        20     22-10
     1        mark        30     22-10
     2        kane        50     22-12  
     2        kane        60     22-12
     3        mike        60     22-10
```

and I want to get an output like that

```
 empID   name      amt      Date    TOTAL
 -----------------------------------------
     1     mark    20      22-10    220
     1     mark    30      22-10    220
     2     kane    50      22-12    220
     2     kane    60      22-12    220
     3     mike     60     22-10    220
```

I have used `sum(amt)` but it is returning only 1 row; I want other rows as well.

Comment: You need `SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`

Comment: i have already written what i have tried. @DaleK

Comment: @Zhorov That is a cumulative running total, not a grand total

Comment: Yes, @Charlieface, this suggestion seems reasonable. Probably the OP needs to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window function `sum() over()` without any `partition` or `order by`

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,[Total] = sum(amt) over()
 From  YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a windowing function

```
SELECT
     empid
    ,name
    ,amt
    ,[date]
    ,SUM(amt) OVER(PARTITION BY '') AS Total -- as you show it
    ,SUM(amt) OVER(PARTITION BY empID) AS Total -- as I think you want it
FROM t
```

> Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to display the grand total value for each row you don't need to partition or group by. Therefore, you can use SUM(amt) OVER () .

```
 SELECT  *, 
 SUM(amt) OVER () AS [Total]     
 FROM tabe_c
```

[image: Result]